# Rectangle is not moving

Tags: javascript, draw

I am trying to code a rectangle moving but it is not working and I do not understand why. I created a class for the rectangle and gave the parameters value. Then I drew the rectangle. I am trying to add the value of 5 to the rectangle's x but nothing is happening.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var width = 50;

class Rectangle{
  constructor(x, y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  draw(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, width, height);
    ctx.fillStyle = "0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }
}

function movingRectangle(){
  var rect = new Rectangle(canvas.width/2 - width/2, 300);
  rect.draw();
  rect.x += 5;
}

function draw(){
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  movingRectangle();
}

var interval = setInterval(draw, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're recreating `rect` on each `movingRectangle()` call, effectively resetting its position to the initial value.

Move this:

```
var rect = new Rectangle(canvas.width/2 - width/2, 300);
```

Out of the `movingRectangle()` function - you only need to create the `Rectangle` instance once.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do a short example, based in your code, and leaving the Rectangle constructor outside:

```
function movingRectangle(){
    let x = rect ? rect.x + 5 : canvas.width/2 - width/2;
  if (!rect)
    rect = new Rectangle(x, 300);
  rect.x = x;
  rect.draw();
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nicoavn/vc254q0a/4/